# Define generic type for use in closure

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

I would like to define a generic type for use in a closure that is defined as an instance variable on a class.  I want to pass in an array of a generic type and ensure that the same type coming out is the same as the one that goes in.  I have written it like this (using Swift 2.0), but it does not build:

```
    var resultProcessing     :  <T: MyObjectType>((obj:Array<T>) -> Array<T>)?
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `resultProcessing` is a variable and variable must have specific type and can not be generic.

Generic functions and classes are useful for defining some algorithms that are common for many types. 
Imagine that you have different algorithms that can be applied to array of any type (for example, different sorting algorithms). So you implement generic function for each algorithm:

```
func myFunc1<T>(obj: [T]) -> [T] {
  // body
}

func myFunc2<T>(obj: [T]) -> [T] {
  // body
}
```

In context where you will apply this functions you always will have specific type. For example, your array will consist of strings:

```
let myArray = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

Next you define variable that will be assigned to specific function based on your conditions:

```
var myFunc: ([String] -> [String])?

if myConditionIsTrue {
    myFunc = myFunc1
} else {
    myFunc = myFunc2
}
```

Then you can call apply function to array:

```
myFunc?(myArray)
```

I think this is what you need in your case. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I need.  I guess I figured it would be possible to apply the same implementation to closures since they share some of the same properties to begin with.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @sashimiblade If my answer was helpful please consider to upvote or/and accept it.